# How can I see modificated code, where inline functions are preprocessed

Tags: c++

I want to see with my own eyes, how my program code changes if i use/(or don't) `inline` key-word in method definition.

My questions:

1) wich environment module create the final version of code (taking into account inline-functions).
When i say "*final version*" I meen a code version in the form in which it is still possible to read (in the c++ language) ? 
(i suppose, this module is like preprocessor, but preprocessor don't preprocess inline functions)

2) How can i see such "final code" (where all mentioned modifications are already done)?

PS: I have Visual Studio 2013 Express

Comment: It doesn't. `inline` no longer has much (if any) effect on whether your code is actually inlined by the optimizer. The compiler will do what it wants. All `inline` does is allow multiple definitions to not cause errors. Not posting as answer 'cause I don't know enough about the rest of the question to say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From when I used C/C++, which was quite long time ago:

1) There's no such thing. Inlining is applied to generated assembly (which btw is still possible to read but it's not C++).

2) As I said, no such code is generated, but you can see the resulting assembly.

Comment: On my MS Visual Studio 2005 system, when execution is stopped at a breakpoint in the relevant function, I can press Ctrl+F11 to see the assembly code

Comment: On MS Visual Studio 2013 Express it works too.
PS: Thanks to all.

Comment: @anatolyg Most IDEs allow that.